# Overlaying an image over WP Supersized Plugin full screen background slideshow

Tags: wordpress, overlay, supersized

I've been struggling with this for days now and I really can't work out how to add an overlay image on top of my full screen slideshow background.

I thought it would be as simple as placing a styled DIV around the supersized 'ul', but I can't even find where to do this.

Here is a link to my site so far: http://www.vinylsoundfiles.co.uk/autonamy

and here is a link to the pattern that I'd like to overlay: http://vinylsoundfiles.co.uk/autonomy/wp-content/themes/garnish/images/header-pattern-light.png

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Below is my code as shown when I 'inspect element'. You can see the ul at the bottom, which is what I presume I need to put my styled div around, however I don't know where to find this ul element and even if I do find it, I'm not sure if this solution to my objective will work.

```
[code]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en-US">
    <head></head>
    <body class="home page page-id-45 page-template-default gecko layout-2cl">
        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>
        <div id="fancybox-loading"></div>
        <div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>
        <div id="fancybox-wrap"></div>
        <ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;"></ul>
    </body>
   [code]
```

Comment: Can you come up with a small example of the problem?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Hey, Yes, sorry. Please see my edit of the original post.